# Design Pattern to merge two implementations into one class

Tags: python, inheritance, design-patterns, python-2.x

I can't figure out the correct way to model this problem.
Here I give you a minimalistic version of my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class AreaCalculator():
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def getArea(self):
        pass

    def compute(self):
        self.getArea()


class PerimeterCalculator():
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def getPerimeter(self):
        pass

    def compute(self):
        self.getPerimeter()


class TriangleAreaCalculator(AreaCalculator):

    def __init__(self):
        AreaCalculator.__init__(self)

    def getArea(self):
        return area

class TrianglePerimeterCalculator(PerimeterCalculator):

    def __init__(self):
        PerimeterCalculator.__init__(self)

    def getPerimeter(self):
        return perimeter



a = TriangleAreaCalculator()
b = TrianglePerimeterCalculator()
```

Is there an elegant way to merge "TrianglePerimeterCalculator" and "TriangleAreaCalculator" classes into one, but keeping "PerimeterCalculator" and "AreaCalculator" separated?

[edit] As Kyle suggested in the comments, I can create a new class (let's call it "Triangle") that inherits from "PerimeterCalculator" and "AreaCalculator" at the same time, but what I want is to be able to tell a new instance of "Triangle" to behave as "PerimeterCalculator" or "AreaCalculator", but not both at the same time.

Comment: You can experiment with creating a more generic "Triangle" class that has a perimeter and area method.

Comment: You can inherit from multiple classes in Python.  class CustomClass(BaseClass1, BaseClass2):

Comment: Yes... that solves the problem, but I would like a new "Triangle" instance to behave as "PerimeterCalculator" or "AreaCalculator" but not both at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another answer, following the editing and clarification of your question. It allows creation of a *single* `Triangle` instance that can behave like either an `AreaCalculator` or `PerimeterCalculator`, as needed.

This programming pattern is called "delegation" and is used where the responsibility for implementing a particular operation is handed off to a different object—in this case an internally held instance of some other class. A common way to do this in Python is by overriding the class's default `__getattr__()` method.

Since you've never responded to the comment under my other answer about exactly what it is that controls which behavior is used, I added a `set_behavior()` method to allow it to be specified explicitly.

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod


class AreaCalculator:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def getArea(self):
        pass

    def compute(self):
        return self.getArea()


class PerimeterCalculator:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def getPerimeter(self):
        pass

    def compute(self):
        return self.getPerimeter()


class TriangleAreaCalculator(AreaCalculator):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TriangleAreaCalculator, self).__init__()

    def getArea(self):
        print('TriangleAreaCalculator.getArea() called')
        area = 13
        return area



class TrianglePerimeterCalculator(PerimeterCalculator):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TrianglePerimeterCalculator, self).__init__()

    def getPerimeter(self):
        print('TrianglePerimeterCalculator.getPerimeter() called')
        perimeter = 42
        return perimeter


class Triangle:

    def __init__(self):
        delegate_classes = TriangleAreaCalculator, TrianglePerimeterCalculator

        # Map delegate classes to instances of themselves.
        self._delegates = {delegate_class: delegate_class()
                            for delegate_class in delegate_classes}

        self.set_behavior(TriangleAreaCalculator)  # Set default delegate.

    def __getattr__(self, attrname):
        # Called only for attributes not defined by this class (or its bases).
        # Retrieve attribute from current behavior delegate class instance.
        return getattr(self._behavior, attrname)

    def set_behavior(self, delegate_class):
        try:
            self._behavior = self._delegates[delegate_class]
        except KeyError:
            raise TypeError("{} isn't a valid {} behavior delegate class"
                              .format(delegate_class, self.__class__.__name__))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    triangle = Triangle()
    # Uses instance's default behavior.
    print('triangle.compute() -> {}'.format(triangle.compute()))

    triangle.set_behavior(TrianglePerimeterCalculator)  # Change behavior.
    print('triangle.compute() -> {}'.format(triangle.compute()))
```

Output:

```
TriangleAreaCalculator.getArea() called
triangle.compute() -> 13
TrianglePerimeterCalculator.getPerimeter() called
triangle.compute() -> 42
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the "design pattern" you should use is multiple inheritance. Below is a modified version of your code demonstrating how do it (plus a few other changes to make it actually runnable and all classes new-style).

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class AreaCalculator(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def getArea(self):
        pass

    def compute(self):
        self.getArea()


class PerimeterCalculator(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def getPerimeter(self):
        pass

    def compute(self):
        self.getPerimeter()


class TriangleAreaCalculator(AreaCalculator):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TriangleAreaCalculator, self).__init__()

    def getArea(self):
        print('TriangleAreaCalculator.getArea() called on instance of {}'.format(
            self.__class__.__name__))
#        return area
        return 13

class TrianglePerimeterCalculator(PerimeterCalculator):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TrianglePerimeterCalculator, self).__init__()

    def getPerimeter(self):
        print('TrianglePerimeterCalculator.getPerimeter() called on instance of {}'.format(
            self.__class__.__name__))
#        return perimeter
        return 42


class MergedCalculator(TriangleAreaCalculator, TrianglePerimeterCalculator):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MergedCalculator, self).__init__()

merged = MergedCalculator()
print('merged.getArea() -> {}'.format(merged.getArea()))
print('merged.getPerimeter() -> {}'.format(merged.getPerimeter()))
```

Output:

```
TriangleAreaCalculator.getArea() called on instance of MergedCalculator
merged.getArea() -> 13
TrianglePerimeterCalculator.getPerimeter() called on instance of MergedCalculator
merged.getPerimeter() -> 42
```

Comment: Thanks martineau. The problem with your answer is that "MergedCalculator" now behaves as AreaCalculator and PerimeterCalculator at the same time, but I needed to be able to instatiate objects that behave as one of them, but not both at the same time. I really appreciate your answer and gave you +1 because it was of great help to figure out the solution. Thanks!

Comment: caspillaga: You're welcome. What determines when your merged class acts like one or the other of the other classes if it's not all of the time? In other words, how does it "know" which way to behave?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself, with inspiration on the commentas/answers of Kyle and martineau.

I can create a merged class "Triangle" as follows:

```
class Triangle():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def getTriangleArea(self):
        print 'Triangle area'

    def getTrianglePerimeter(self):
        print 'Triangle perimeter'
```

And then modify TriangleAreaCalculator and TrianglePerimeterCalculator as follows:

```
class TriangleAreaCalculator(AreaCalculator, Triangle):

    def __init__(self):
        TriangleCalculator.__init__(self)
        AreaCalculator.__init__(self)

    def getArea(self):
        super(TriangleAreaCalculator, self).getTriangleArea()

class TrianglePerimeterCalculator(PerimeterCalculator, Triangle):

    def __init__(self):
        TriangleCalculator.__init__(self)
        PerimeterCalculator.__init__(self)

    def getPerimeter(self):
        super(TrianglePerimeterCalculator, self).getTrianglePerimeter()
```

This way, I can create a new Triangle-like instance that behaves as "PerimeterCalculator" or "AreaCalculator" (but not both at the same time):

```
a = TriangleAreaCalculator()
b = TrianglePerimeterCalculator()

a.compute() # correctly prints "Triangle area"
b.compute() # correctly prints "Triangle perimeter"
```

Comment: I don't think the calculators should inherit from the Triangle class

Comment: True... After a second thought I see that it does the job, but in a very ugly way. Definitely not the "correct way"